# Throw exception when DomainClassConverter can't find entity with @PathVariable

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data

For instance:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/item")
class ItemController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = GET)
    Item get(@PathVariable("id") Item item) {
        return item;
    }
}
```

I don't want to handle every time the case which DomainClassConverter returns null when some record doesn't exist. I would like that an exception was thrown automatically. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,Check if no item found throw custom exception.

```
class ItemNotFoundException extends Exception{  
       ItemNotFoundException(String s){  
      super(s);  
     }  
  }
```

And change your code like this and handle exception according your need.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/item")
class ItemController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = GET)
    Item get(@PathVariable("id") Item item) {
        if(item ==null){
            throw new ItemNotFoundException("No item found.");  
        }else{
            return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm trying to avoid, I would like to handle it automatically. In fact, I have already solved the problem but my solution seemed a bit odd. So I would like to know if there is another way that I'm not aware of.